# Select the next row in a ag-grid-table via button (also if the next row would be on the next page)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ag-grid

I'm using ag-grid in an AngularJS 1.6 project. In this specific case I have a table via ag-grid and select a single row via click ( no multirow-selection possible). I want to to some stuff with this rowdata (which does not matter here) and via button I want to preselect the next row after this one. I did this via

component:

```
// ag-grid event-hook
function onSelectionChanged() {
    ctrl.selectedItem = ctrl.gridOptions.api.getSelectedRows()[0];
    ctrl.selectedRowIndex = ctrl.gridOptions.api.getSelectedNodes()[0].rowIndex;
    $scope.$apply();

    doOtherStuff();
}

[...]

// function on button via ng-click
function selectNextItemInTable() {
    agGridService.selectGridRow(ctrl.gridOptions, ctrl.selectedRowIndex + 1);
}

[...]
```

agGridService:

```
function selectGridRow(gridOptions, index) {
    if(!gridOptions || !gridOptions.api) {
        return;
    }
    var rowNode = gridOptions.api.getDisplayedRowAtIndex(index);
    if(rowNode) {
        rowNode.setSelected(true);
    }
}
```

It works if the selected item is not the last one on a table page, but if it is the last, it unfortunately does not preselect the first item on the next page but instead no row at all. How can I do that?

/Edit: I just noticed that it DOES select the next row in the list, it just does not change the page! If I change it manually I can see that the next row is selected... So The only thing I need is a check if I have to change the page via api...

Comment: for next page you need to pass selection data with query like ...url?selection=121 ... then check and select

Comment: It is an AngularJS SPA, so that's not correct... sorry.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `gridOptions.api.getLastDisplayedRow()`.

This will give you the last rowID visible on the current page. lets say if pagination is of size 10 and we are on 1st page then this option will return 9(array index logic). check this number with your current selected row, if this number is equal to your current selected row then you can call  `gridOptions.api.paginationGoToNextPage();`

you can use below condition to check if you are on the last page or not.

```
    gridOptions.api.paginationGetCurrentPage() < gridOptions.api.paginationGetTotalPages()
```

hope this helps, let me know if you need more help.